# How to model weak entity in ER diagram?

Tags: database-design, erd

I was going through the weak entity concepts and was trying to model the relation `Hotel has many rooms`. I have come up with the partial solution presented below but i'm having a problem to uniquely identify the tuples in the room entity related to the specific hotel.

**My Assumption**

1. Hotel(hotel_number, name) is a strong entity.
2. Rooms(room_number, bed) is a weak entity whose existence depends on the existence of the hotel.

[image: Modeled ER Diagram]

**1. Hotel entity's table**

| hotel_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 125 | n1 |
| 132 | n2 |
| 173 | n3 |
| 103 | n4 |
| 193 | n5 |

**2. Room entity's table**

| room_number | beds |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 3 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 103 | 6 |

There are two hotels with hotel_id 125 and 132. Hotel with hotel_id 125 has room numbered 101 with 3 beds and another hotel has room_number 101 with 2 beds. So how can i model the given relation in such condition as there's no pk for the weak entity i.e. room ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Room should have PK of (hotel_id,room_number).

Weak entities have compound keys with the strong entity key/foreign key as the leading column(s).

There are people who disagree with this approach, but they are wrong.

> How can i find the room belonging to specific hotel which has the different number of beds limiting the attributes in the domain of my problem

Something like:

```
select *
from rooms
where hotel_id  = 1001
  and beds = 3
```

Comment: So if i were to implement that in SQL i've to create a table for the weak entity with the partial key and the foreign key(from the pk of strong entity participating in relation).This is what i was taught in my DBMS course for mapping weak entity into relational schema.   Still my confusion is `How can i find the room belonging to specific hotel which has the different number of beds limiting the attributes in the domain of my problem ?`.  In the domain of the problem theres no such attributes that can be used as pk for hotel though i can add the ID as a new field to the hotel.

Comment: But the attribute ID doesnt belong to the domain i'm trying to model i.e. ID has no meaning to the hotel entity.

Comment: Like many entities, a Hotel has a Name, but that can change, and isn't necessarily unique.  So you introduce a "synthetic" or "artificial" key.

Comment: Thanks for your time @Browne - Microsoft.          `To identify a entry in the room for specific hotel i need beds and the hotel_number. Which implies partial key for weak entity(room) is going to be  bed.`  Correct me if i'm wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The real question is *why is there no **primary key** for the `Rooms` table?* In most cases (except a few edge cases like **staging tables**) you should have a **primary key** on your tables.

Despite this, even without a **primary key** on the `Rooms` table, it looks like the relationship is naturally many-to-one with `Hotels` (that is any room can only belong to one hotel), and therefore you could at least add a **foreign key** field to the `Rooms` table on `hotel_id`. So your **foreign key constraint** would be on `Rooms.hotel_id` to `Hotels.hotel_id`.

But my recommendation would be to add both a **primary key** and then **foreign key** field to your `Rooms` table. Without doing at least one of those things, it's not possible to establish a relationship between `Rooms` and `Hotels`. The **primary key** on the `Rooms` table would be defined on `hotel_id, room_number`.

Comment: A bit confused here.  ``But my recommendation would be to add both a primary key and then foreign key field to your Rooms table. Without doing at least one of those things, it's not possible to establish a relationship between Rooms and Hotels.`` If so then what's the purpose of relation ``has``.

Comment: And there's pk in the room entity, because that's going to be the weak entity.

Comment: @sbhusal123 I'm not familiar with the syntax of your **ER** diagram, but it's not possible to relate the two without a field for them to relate on. Right now I don't see a field in your `Rooms` table that is relatable between the two (which I think is your whole issue). Which field is the **primary key** in your `Rooms` table?

Comment: Weak entity dont have primary key that's the reason we call it weak. And the existence of such entity depends on the strong entity

Comment: @Sbhusal123 Sorry I misunderstood your last reply thinking you said that *there is a **primary key***. Anyway see David Browne's answer confirming what I said about using a **primary key** (or alternatively just a **foreign key** on `hotel_id`) to establish the relationship. Without either of these, there is no relationship defined. (P.s. he works for Microsoft, so I think he knows his stuff. :)

Comment: @sbhusal123 don't confuse the model with the implementation. The table Rooms (with the foreign key and the composite PK) implements both the Has and Room entities.

Comment: You could implement them in separate tables but that is not common with a one-to-many relationship.